# Things star trek predicted wrong

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I think of Star Trek to be the forerunner of today's inventions/culture. Most of what is available/happens in the Enterprise becomes reality soon thereafter (Touch displays, holographic projections, diversity of people collaborating etc.,) However there are things Star Trek that has gone wrong such as Captain Picard saying in one of the TNG episodes that Fermat's last theorem is yet to be solved in the 24th Century (which was later solved in the year 1995 by the Mathematician Andrew Wiles). What other things Star trek famously predicted wrong?

Comment: Touchscreens [existed prior to TNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchscreen#History), and I don't think any were shown in the original series. The first practical holograms were [demonstrated in 1962](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holography), and it's still basically impossible to freely project images in 3D space as shown on Trek (with holograms there is always some kind of plate or screen along the same line of sight as the apparent 3D image).

Comment: Fermat's last theorem was solved using methods not available in Fermat's time; as far as I know, how Fermat did it is still unknown

Comment: I don't know why this is receiving downvotes. Care to explain, downvoters?

Comment: Thanks for that interesting tidbit, Hypnosifl.

Comment: @Izkata - Yes, Picard's comments in [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHQTcuskl3k) are a bit ambiguous, he says that Fermat said he had a proof and that "for 800 years people have been trying to solve it"--one interpretation could be that he was saying Fermat's theorem had never been proved, but another could be that by "solve it" he meant "solve the mystery of how Fermat might have proven it, given the mathematical knowledge he would have had available", which doesn't rule out the idea that a proof had been found using math that was unknown in Fermat's time.

Comment: I didn't downvote (in fact I upvoted!) but it may be because it's a list question?

Comment: “Most of what is available/happens in the Enterprise becomes reality soon thereafter.” Most? Are we flying through space at warp speed, with artificial gravity, transporting down to planets, shooting phasers, eating food from replicators, and chilling out in the holodeck?

Comment: @Izkata _Whether_ Fermat had a proof is still unknown; the consensus seems to be that he probably didn't. (He may have thought it could be fully proved using his method of [infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent), as he did for the specific case of n=4, and then later realised his mistake — which is why he never mentioned it in his remaining 3 decades.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Quite a few things

This could turn out to be an extremely long list, but I'll focus on the main ones which were mentioned in [this article](http://www.infinitefrontiers.0catch.com/FutureImperfect.htm) as well as a few others I can think of:

- The Eugenics Wars in the 1990s (*Space Seed*); that didn't happen (thank goodness)
- Trans-generational 'sleeper' space ships (*Space Seed* (TOS) and *The Neutral Zone* (TNG)); don't have them yet
- The Voyager Probes being launched in the 20th century; in *The Motion Picture* we have *Voyager **VI***; we're in the *21st* century and have only launched **2**
- A manned mission to Saturn in 2009 (*Tomorrow is Yesterday*); we haven't even put men on Mars yet!
- The launch of the Nomad probe in 2002 (*The Changeling*)

To be fair though, have a look at [this article](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/gallery/2009/may/15/star-trek-technology) which points out a number of technologies which have since been actually developed.

Comment: Nice work, @N_Soong --- you've selected some telling examples, +1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dr.Soong. How is that positronic brain of yours coming along? ;-)

Comment: @TomMickey slowly but surely ;)

Comment: @N_Soong:  I thought you'd be the last one to call your sons' brains "slow"